# Spring LDAP with dynamic base DN

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I have following LDAP scheme:

[image]

Every subtree contains organization unit **Team**. I want to find all Teams from specific subtree. To do that I use `LdapTemplate` class and `findAll()` methods.

```
ldapTemplate.findAll(Team.class);
```

When I set base in `LdapContextSource` to `dc=global,dc=id,dc=pl` it returns me Teams from global subtree. When I change base to `dc=id,dc=pl` it returns me Teams from all subtrees.

The problem is that I want to use dynamic base, to find Teams from specific subtree. I've tried multiple methods to achieve that, but none of them gives me results.

**Method 1: find**

```
Name nameBase = LdapUtils.newLdapName("dc=global");
return ldapTemplate.find(query().base(nameBase).where("ou").is("team"), Team.class);
```

returns **empty list**

**Method 2: findAll**

```
Name nameBase = LdapUtils.newLdapName("dc=global");
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
return ldapTemplate.findAll(nameBase, searchControls, Team.class);
```

returns **empty list**

At first It looks like working correctly, because when I change subtree name to some which not exists I get `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]`

Any ideas why I get proper results in this code:

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setBase("dc=global,dc=id,dc=pl");

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
return ldapTemplate.findAll(Team.class);
```

And empty list from this one:

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setBase("dc=id,dc=pl");

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
Name nameBase = LdapUtils.newLdapName("dc=global");
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
return ldapTemplate.findAll(nameBase, searchControls, Team.class);
```

I use Spring-ldap-core 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution.

**First**

Adding proper scope to `SearchControls`

```
SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
return ldapTemplate.findAll(base, searchControls, Team.class);
```

**Second**

Changing query parameters to check if ***cn*** is present

```
return ldapTemplate.find(query().base(base).where("cn").isPresent(), Team.class);
```